# Basic Laravel command-line program got exception

Tags: php, laravel, command-line

I have stacked in the basic Laravel command-line program. It raises exception when the code accesses the command-line parameter.

### Command-line Program

app/Console/Commands/User/ElasticIndexMaker.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\User;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ElasticIndexMaker extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $signature = 'elasticindexmaker {index: Index specified by the target S3 directry structure starting first character with slash}';
    protected $signature = "elasticindexmaker {index: Index name}";

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate Elasticsearch index';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $index = $this -> argument("index");
        $verboseLog = $this -> option("verbose");

        $this->info("Index: " . $index);
        if ($this->confirm("Are you sure to generate index by this parameter?")) {
        } else {
            return;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

app/Console/Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\User\ElasticIndexMaker::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands/User');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

### Phenominon

#### 1. Specifying `-h` to command-line works fine

```
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel> php artisan elasticindexmaker -h     
Description:
  Generate Elasticsearch index

Usage:
  elasticindexmaker <index: Index name>

Arguments:
  index: Index name     

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command    
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel>
```

#### 2. Specifying parameter gets exception

```
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel> php artisan elasticindexmaker aa/bb

  The "index" argument does not exist.  

PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel>
```

Debugging with VSCode shows that Laravel does not recognize the `index` command-line parameter.

```
Exception has occurred.
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException: No arguments expected for "elasticindexmaker" command, got "aa/bb".
```

[image: Debugging screen]

Point me what is wrong with this command-line program.

### Running environment

Windows 10

```
PS D:\My_Documents\Proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel> php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.20.1
```

Excerpt from composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.171",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.6",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
```

Regards,

Comment: Add a space before the colon in the signature. From what I can tell, that makes a difference. `{index : Index name}`

Comment: @aynber Thank you! You are the life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

@aynber's suggestion solves this problem.

app/Console/Commands/User/ElasticIndexMaker.php

```
protected $signature = "elasticindexmaker {index : Index name}";
```

The command-line works fine.

[image: Command-line snapshot]